# Why can't I insert a breakpoint here (I might add all my friends can, and I see no other way to solve this)

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

```
(gdb) list 1,20
1   int swap_n_add(int *xp, int *yp)
2   {
3       int x = *xp;
4       int y = *yp;
5   
6       *xp = y;
7       *yp = x;
8       return x + y;
9   }
10  
11  int main() {
12      int a1 = 534;
13      int a2 = 1057;
14      int sum = swap_n_add(&a1, &a2);
15      int diff = a1 - a2;
16  
17      return sum * diff;
18  }
(gdb) b 18
No line 18 in file "swap_n_add.c".
```

I want to check the value main returns, so I put a breakpoint at 18 to inspect the register there (`info register`). But it says that line doesn't exist, despite it... saying it does exist. And my friends with identical code can put it there.

Comment: Are you sure you are debugging against the binary you compiled? A guess is that the source code changed after the binary was generated.

Comment: are you compiling with  `-g`? (if gcc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would question the previous setup steps that you haven't shown. If your friend's are able to set a breakpoint there and you are not, there is probably something you did wrong. (assuming everyone is using the same versions of all the tools)

with gdb version 7.4-2012.04 for Ubuntu and gcc 4.6.3 I can see and set a break point at the line in question:

```
> gcc -Wall -g file.c      <-- compile with -g for debug symbols
> gdb a.out                <-- run against the executable
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".     <-- make sure it was configured for 
For bug reporting instructions, please see:            your architecture
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /home/mike/C/a.out...done.   <-- and that your file loads symbols
(gdb) line 22, 39
22   int swap_n_add(int *xp, int *yp)   <-- mine are different because I have a bunch
23   {                                      of #include's in my test file
24      int x = *xp;
25      int y = *yp;
26  
27      *xp = y;
28      *yp = x;
29      return x + y;
30  }
31  
32  int main() {
33      int a1 = 534;
34      int a2 = 1057;
35      int sum = swap_n_add(&a1, &a2);
36      int diff = a1 - a2;
37  
38      return sum * diff;
39  }
(gdb) b 39
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400530: file file.c, line 39.
```

Note that if I pick a line outside of the file, say.. 75, it gives you a message about "no line x in file":

```
(gdb) b 75
No line 75 in the current file.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

If you're seeing this it's worth double checking your line numbers, it's possible you mis-counted.

If you want to see the value of the return (`sum * diff`) you can always set that to a local variable before returning and break on the return.

Comment: He can't have mis-counted: the `list` output is right there. But he might have updated the source after it has been compiled, or he might have compiled with optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

This may be compiler/debugger-specific. There may be no debug information generated for the closing brace.

Also, if you have optimization enabled, it can make it hard or impossible to put breakpoints at some locations. Try removing the `-O` parameter to gcc, if you use it.

If it still doesn't help, assign the return value to a new variable and return that variable instead.

Alternatively, you could just switch to the disassembly, put a breakpoint on the `ret` instruction of `main()` (the instruction that does function return on x86) and examine the returned value in the CPU registers (should be in `eax` on x86).